# How to parse json in spark using user-defined-function?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd

I'm working on a project that includes kafka, spark and hive. I've an event example like this,

```
{"event": "OrderEvent", "messageid": "2db62eb5-de95-4ce8-8161-ab7552dc2fd7", "userid": "user-346", "lineitems": [{"productid": "product-784", "quantity": 3}, {"productid": "product-173", "quantity": 1}], "orderid": 50000}
```

There's a consumer job that subscribe a kafka topic and consumes events, then writes them into hdfs (my hive table's location)

My problem is, I want to write a function to parse json event to string for each row but I got
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'repartition'`

My whole consumer job is like

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import json


class OrderEventConsumer:

def __init__(self):
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName('OrderEventConsumer')
    self.sc = SparkContext().getOrCreate(conf)
    self.sc.setLogLevel('ERROR')
    self.ssc = StreamingContext(self.sc, 5)
    self.ssc.checkpoint('/tmp/SparkCheckpoints')
    sqlContext = SQLContext(self.sc)

    # Kafka variables
    self.zkQuorum = 'localhost:2189'
    self.topic = 'test'  # 'prod-raw-product-view'

def format_event(self, rdd):
    for i in range(len(rdd['lineitems'])):
        yield '{},{},{},{},{},{}'.format(rdd['userid'], rdd['orderid'], rdd['lineitems'][i]['productid'],
                                         rdd['lineitems'][i]['quantity'], rdd['messageid'], rdd['event_time'])

def consume(self):
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(self.ssc, self.zkQuorum, 'spark-streaming-consumer', {self.topic: 1})
    aRdd = kvs.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])) \
        .foreachRDD(lambda x: x.foreach(lambda x: self.format_event(x))) \
        .repartition(1) \
        .saveAsTextFiles('hdfs://node1/user/hive/warehouse/hb.db/fact_order/')
    self.ssc.start()
    self.ssc.awaitTermination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    orderConsumer = OrderEventConsumer()
    orderConsumer.consume()
```

I want to write a file to hdfs includes lineitems count times row for each event.
How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `foreachRDD` and `foreach` functions - they are not returning any data.  If you want to format your things, just use `map` as you did in the previous line.

Also, don't use `repartition`, but instead use `coalesce` - it could be much faster

P.S. If you're just starting, I would recommend to use Spark Structured Streaming - it could be more performant and easier to sue than Spark Streaming.